# YOLOv8 get predicted class name

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo

I just want to get class data in my python script like: *person, car, truck, dog*  but my output more than this. Also I can not use results as a string.

**Python script:**

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt") 
results = model.predict(source="0")
```

**Output:**

```
0: 480x640 1 person, 1 car, 7.1ms
0: 480x640 1 person, 1 car, 7.2ms
0: 480x640 1 person, 1 car, 7.1ms
0: 480x640 1 person, 1 car, 7.1ms
0: 480x640 1 person, 1 car, 7.1ms
0: 480x640 1 person, 7.9ms
0: 480x640 1 person, 7.1ms
0: 480x640 1 person, 1 car, 7.1ms
0: 480x640 1 person, 1 car, 7.1ms
```

Comment: A simple internet search will get you a long way: https://inside-machinelearning.com/en/yolov8-how-to-use/

Comment: Iterate over results[0].boxes.boxes, they are in the format [x1, y1, x2, y2, score, label]. Use the int(label) as the index for your class list.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass each class to the model's name dict like this:

```py
from ultralytics.yolo.engine.model import YOLO
  
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
results = model.predict(stream=True, imgsz=512) # source already setup
names = model.names

for r in results:
    for c in r.boxes.cls:
        print(names[int(c)])
```

output:

```bash
YOLOv8n summary (fused): 168 layers, 3151904 parameters, 0 gradients, 8.7 GFLOPs
bus
person
person
person
person
image 1/2 /home/xyz/ultralytics/ultralytics/assets/bus.jpg: 512x384 4 persons, 1 bus, 35.7ms
person
person
person
tie
tie
image 2/2 /home/xyz/ultralytics/ultralytics/assets/zidane.jpg: 288x512 3 persons, 2 ties, 199.0ms
Speed: 3.9ms pre-process, 117.4ms inference, 27.9ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 512, 512)
```

Comment: Same output ```from ultralytics.yolo.engine.model import YOLO

def main():  
    model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
    results = model.predict(imgsz=512, stream=True, source="0") # source already setup

    for r in results:
        for c in r.boxes.cls:
            print(model.names[int(c)])

main()```

Comment: You added a print so something must change

Comment: print does not effect anything. I tried many times. Also my file path: /home/gursel/ultralytics/test.py  is it okay?

Comment: try: `pip install --upgrade ultralytics`

Comment: I did it but I get an error when I added stream: stream is not a valid key. Similar keys: []

Comment: It is solved I recloned ultralytics repo. Also code works correctly thanks! @Mike B

Answer (score 0):

code with a single loop

```
clist= res[0].boxes.cls
cls = set()
for cno in clist:
    cls.add(model.names[int(cno)])

print(cls)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.