# Obtaining detected object names using YOLOv8

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-detection, yolo, yolov8

We are trying to get the detected object names using Python and YOLOv8 with the following code.

```
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO


def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

    model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        result = model(frame, agnostic_nms=True)[0]

        print(result)

        if cv2.waitKey(30) == 27:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The following two types are shown on the log.

```
0: 384x640 1 person, 151.2ms
Speed: 0.6ms preprocess, 151.2ms inference, 1.8ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
```

The second log is the one we displayed using `print`, how do we get the `person` from now on? Presumably we get the `person` by giving 0 to the `names`, but where do we get the 0 from?

```
ultralytics.yolo.engine.results.Results object with attributes:

boxes: ultralytics.yolo.engine.results.Boxes object
keypoints: None
keys: ['boxes']
masks: None
names: {0: 'person', 1: 'bicycle', 2: 'car', 3: 'motorcycle', 4: 'airplane', 5: 'bus', 6: 'train', 7: 'truck', 8: 'boat', 9: 'traffic light', 10: 'fire hydrant', 11: 'stop sign', 12: 'parking meter', 13: 'bench', 14: 'bird', 15: 'cat', 16: 'dog', 17: 'horse', 18: 'sheep', 19: 'cow', 20: 'elephant', 21: 'bear', 22: 'zebra', 23: 'giraffe', 24: 'backpack', 25: 'umbrella', 26: 'handbag', 27: 'tie', 28: 'suitcase', 29: 'frisbee', 30: 'skis', 31: 'snowboard', 32: 'sports ball', 33: 'kite', 34: 'baseball bat', 35: 'baseball glove', 36: 'skateboard', 37: 'surfboard', 38: 'tennis racket', 39: 'bottle', 40: 'wine glass', 41: 'cup', 42: 'fork', 43: 'knife', 44: 'spoon', 45: 'bowl', 46: 'banana', 47: 'apple', 48: 'sandwich', 49: 'orange', 50: 'broccoli', 51: 'carrot', 52: 'hot dog', 53: 'pizza', 54: 'donut', 55: 'cake', 56: 'chair', 57: 'couch', 58: 'potted plant', 59: 'bed', 60: 'dining table', 61: 'toilet', 62: 'tv', 63: 'laptop', 64: 'mouse', 65: 'remote', 66: 'keyboard', 67: 'cell phone', 68: 'microwave', 69: 'oven', 70: 'toaster', 71: 'sink', 72: 'refrigerator', 73: 'book', 74: 'clock', 75: 'vase', 76: 'scissors', 77: 'teddy bear', 78: 'hair drier', 79: 'toothbrush'}
orig_img: array([[[51, 58, 64],
        [52, 59, 65],
        [54, 59, 65],
        ...,
        [64, 68, 74],
        [62, 67, 73],
        [62, 67, 73]],

       [[51, 58, 64],
        [53, 59, 65],
        [54, 59, 65],
        ...,
        [63, 68, 74],
        [62, 67, 73],
        [62, 67, 73]],

       [[53, 58, 64],
        [53, 58, 64],
        [53, 58, 64],
        ...,
        [61, 67, 73],
        [61, 67, 73],
        [61, 67, 73]],

       ...,

       [[43, 48, 58],
        [42, 47, 57],
        [41, 46, 56],
        ...,
        [24, 35, 49],
        [23, 34, 48],
        [23, 34, 48]],

       [[44, 48, 59],
        [43, 47, 57],
        [42, 46, 56],
        ...,
        [26, 35, 49],
        [26, 35, 49],
        [24, 33, 48]],

       [[45, 48, 59],
        [43, 45, 56],
        [40, 43, 54],
        ...,
        [26, 35, 49],
        [26, 35, 49],
        [25, 33, 48]]], dtype=uint8)
orig_shape: (720, 1280)
path: 'image0.jpg'
probs: None
speed: {'preprocess': 1.6682147979736328, 'inference': 79.47301864624023, 'postprocess': 1.0020732879638672}
```

We would like to know the solution in this way. But if it is not possible, we can use another method if it is a combination of Python and YOLOv8. We plan to display bounding boxes and object names.

### Additional Information

I changed the code as follows.

```
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # result = model(frame, agnostic_nms=True)[0]
        result = model([frame])[0]

        boxes = result.boxes
        masks = result.masks
        probs = result.probs

        print("[boxes]==============================")
        print(boxes)
        print("[masks]==============================")
        print(masks)
        print("[probs]==============================")
        print(probs)
```

After all, the following `person` is not included. How should we determine that?

```
[boxes]==============================
WARNING ⚠️ 'Boxes.boxes' is deprecated. Use 'Boxes.data' instead.
ultralytics.yolo.engine.results.Boxes object with attributes:

boxes: tensor([[4.7356e+01, 7.2858e+00, 1.1974e+03, 7.1092e+02, 8.6930e-01, 0.0000e+00]])
cls: tensor([0.])
conf: tensor([0.8693])
data: tensor([[4.7356e+01, 7.2858e+00, 1.1974e+03, 7.1092e+02, 8.6930e-01, 0.0000e+00]])
id: None
is_track: False
orig_shape: tensor([ 720, 1280])
shape: torch.Size([1, 6])
xywh: tensor([[ 622.4028,  359.1004, 1150.0942,  703.6293]])
xywhn: tensor([[0.4863, 0.4988, 0.8985, 0.9773]])
xyxy: tensor([[  47.3557,    7.2858, 1197.4500,  710.9150]])
xyxyn: tensor([[0.0370, 0.0101, 0.9355, 0.9874]])
[masks]==============================
None
[probs]==============================
None
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YOLOv8 get predicted class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75277492/yolov8-get-predicted-class-name)

Comment: I have not confirmed that yet.
But I see it looks like the answer we were looking for.

We didn't find it before the question.
Thanks.

Comment: Please, confirm if it is the case so that be don't bloat stack overflow with duplicated questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably better solutions to this, but I couldn't really find anything useful either, so I did this:

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    results = model(frame, agnostic_nms=True)[0]

    if not results or len(results) == 0:
        continue

    for result in results:

        detection_count = result.boxes.shape[0]

        for i in range(detection_count):
            cls = int(result.boxes.cls[i].item())
            name = result.names[cls]
            confidence = float(result.boxes.conf[i].item())
            bounding_box = result.boxes.xyxy[i].cpu().numpy()

            x = int(bounding_box[0])
            y = int(bounding_box[1])
            width = int(bounding_box[2] - x)
            height = int(bounding_box[3] - y)
```

Comment: The answer I wanted to know is this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get it as follows I have not yet figured out if this is correct.

```
        print(result.names[int(result.boxes.cls[0])])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through each frame in a video, extracting all the class names found in each frame

```py
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    
    # BGR to RGB conversion is performed under the hood
    # see: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/2575
    results = model.predict(img)

    for r in results:
        
        boxes = r.boxes
        for box in boxes:
            
            c = box.cls
            print(model.names[int(c)])
```

output example

```bash
0: 480x640 2 persons, 57.4ms
Speed: 1.5ms preprocess, 57.4ms inference, 1.0ms postprocess, 0.0ms tracking per image at shape (1, 3, 480, 640)
person
person

0: 480x640 2 persons, 54.3ms
Speed: 1.3ms preprocess, 54.3ms inference, 1.0ms postprocess, 0.0ms tracking per image at shape (1, 3, 480, 640)
person
person

0: 480x640 2 persons, 60.5ms
Speed: 1.3ms preprocess, 60.5ms inference, 1.0ms postprocess, 0.0ms tracking per image at shape (1, 3, 480, 640)
person
person
```

Answer (score -1):

```
inputs = [img, img]  # list of numpy arrays
results = model(inputs)  # list of Results objects

for result in results:
    boxes = result.boxes  # Boxes object for bbox outputs
    masks = result.masks  # Masks object for segmentation masks outputs
    probs = result.probs  # Class probabilities for classification outputs
```

Refer [Yolov8 Docs](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We had already tried it, but still it does not contain anything indicating `person`.