# YOLOv8 segmentation get class names when predicting multiple classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, image-segmentation, yolov8

How do I get the class names of segmented instances when detecting multiple classes in YOLOv8? The detections do not have a `.cls` attribute like here [YOLOv8 get predicted class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75277492/yolov8-get-predicted-class-name). Also the docs do not seem to mention anything e.g. [here](https://docs.ultralytics.com/reference/engine/results/#ultralytics.engine.results.Results)

When I use the `show=true` argument in the prediction function, the classes are distinguished in the resulting image, but I cannot get them programmatically. My code that gets me all detections I wanjt but does not let me know which one is which:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("path/to/best.pt")
result = model.predict(os.path.join(cut_dir, im_name), save_conf=True, show=True)
if result[0].masks is not None:
    for counter, detection in enumerate(result[0].masks.data):
         detected = np.asarray(detection.cpu())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the segmentation task, you can refer to the `boxes.cls` property of the result object to get the detected class index, the same as for the detection task. `model.names[class_index]` will return the class name:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("path/to/best.pt")
result = model.predict(os.path.join(cut_dir, im_name), save_conf=True, show=True)
if result[0].masks is not None:
    for counter, detection in enumerate(result[0].masks.data):
         cls_id = int(result[0].boxes[counter].cls.item())
         cls_name = model.names[cls_id]
```